# How to rotate captured image in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am facing a problem while capturing images using intent. The captured image is automatically rotated.
How to prevent the problem. Can someone help?

Comment: Can you add your capturing code to have a better understanding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I hope my solution would still help,

    byte[] data = null;
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.length);
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = null;

    try {

      bitmap = ImageResizer.rotateImageIfRequired(bitmap, context, uri);
      outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outputStream);
      data = outputStream.toByteArray();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      Timber.e(e.getMessage());
      e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
      try {
        if (outputStream != null) {
          outputStream.close();
        }
      } catch (IOException e) {
        // Intentionally blank
      }
    }

    return data;
  }




public static Bitmap rotateImageIfRequired(Bitmap img, Context context, Uri selectedImage) throws IOException {

    if (selectedImage.getScheme().equals("content")) {
      String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION };
      Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, projection, null, null, null);
      if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        final int rotation = c.getInt(0);
        c.close();
        return rotateImage(img, rotation);
      }
      return img;
    } else {
      ExifInterface ei = new ExifInterface(selectedImage.getPath());
      int orientation = ei.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
      Timber.d("orientation: %s", orientation);

      switch (orientation) {
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
          return rotateImage(img, 90);
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
          return rotateImage(img, 180);
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
          return rotateImage(img, 270);
        default:
          return img;
      }
    }
  }

  private static Bitmap rotateImage(Bitmap img, int degree) {
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(degree);
    Bitmap rotatedImg = Bitmap.createBitmap(img, 0, 0, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), matrix, true);
    return rotatedImg;
  }
```